# Redirect using DNS records

Tags: php, cakephp, dns

So I got myself a fancy 'short' domain - abcd.st - I am using this purely as a redirect domain and nothing else. The NIC.st website is more rudimentary than I can imagine. It gives you the ability to add DNS records but nothing much more than that. No access to web server or anything of that sort. It does give you the ability to change DNS servers but I dont know if that would be of help (newbie in this area).

Now, I'll be creating tiny URLs using my add that look like
http://abcd.st/55e0c or http://abcd.st/45qs2s and you get the idea

When a user visits these tiny URLs I need them to be redirected to a specific action on my main website www.abcd.com/pages/view

Using DNS records I am able to redirect all traffic blindly to my primary domain - www.abcd.com - but I am not sure how to

1. Redirect to a specific path
2. Assuming there is no way they can be redirected to a specific path, then is there some way I can find the redirect domain and then internally forward them once more to the correct action?

Edit - here is what my DNS record looks like

```
NAME                TTL        TYPE            ADDRESS

@                   1800       A               xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I am using CakePHP 3.0.10

Help is appreciated!

Comment: what DNS records blindly redirect?  CNAME?  That's not an actual redirect - does the browser actually show the "redirected" domain?

Comment: Reroute all traffic to a static endpoint in your main website, taking in the little ID string and from there determine where to redirect to. The shortcut domain should be just that

Comment: @NG. - if I type in abcd.st in my browser it shows abcd.st but actually loads content from abcd.com

Comment: @scrowler - that is exactly what I would like to do. But all I have access to is the ability to define DNS records - so I cannot specify endpoints. I can only specify IP addresses to which the site must be forwarded / redirected. So in other words, my DNS record looks something like what I have shown in the original question

Comment: Yeah - so you'll need to set up an htaccess rule to route certain patterns to a more defined Cake controller

Comment: It is not possible to do what you ask - dns has no concept of a path, it's for _domain_ name resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I ended up doing

1. I had the DNS records point to my main domain. So if the user went to http://abcd.st, they would get redirected to http://www.abcd.com
2. I configured the central controller in CakePHP, `AppController` check the referring domain. If the referring domain has the 'abcd.st' then it knows that this is a short-hand URL redirect and then pushes it to the appropriate controller / action
3. Additionally, I also used `$this->request->here` to extract all the parameters sent with the original web address and I pass it to the new controller / action

Hope this helps someone in the future...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot redirect urls with specific paths using dns.

I recommend a php redirection script instead. Something like this.

index.php

```
<?php
$site = "http://www.abcd.com/";
$path = "";
switch ($_GET["url"])
{
    case "45qs2s":
        $path = "pages/view/1";
        break;
    case "55e0c":
        $path = "pages/view/2";
        break;
}
http_redirect($site . $path);
?>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^index.php?url=(.*)$ $1
```

Comment: I cannot create a PHP script - I do not have access to the webserver. All I have access to is an admin console where I can define DNS records

Comment: Put the script on a free host & set dns records to their nameservers?

Comment: I like this - but I am going to wait a bit to see if there is a better approach. If not, I'll accept your answer and solution :)